# SQL Query for grouping by user_id, and only getting the most recent (by time), returns limited object

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so 
any input on how I can improve my questions would
be greatly appreciated.  Also, I just started learning sql 
on my own time, so specific answers and explanations help.
Thanks in advance!

I am trying to craft a specific query that pulls
every unique `user_id` row such that it gets the newest entry for that `user_id`. Looking at other posts, I came up with this query:

```
SELECT user_id, max(time) as time 
FROM $session_name 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

The result I would like to see is:

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 3
        [lat] => 1 
        [lon] => 1
        [time] => 2016-03-27 11:30:24
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 1234
        [lat] => 1 
        [lon] => 1
        [time] => 2016-03-27 11:29:46
    )
```

But instead I get:

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 3
        [time] => 2016-03-27 11:30:24
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 1234
        [time] => 2016-03-27 11:29:46
    )
```

I figure that, in my `SELECT` statement, I need to enter the fields `lat` and `lon`, but after experimenting with different queries and reading different posts, the sql entries never executed properly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: can you describe all the tables fileds ? It would be easier with a unique id

Comment: I'm using MYSQL with phpmyadmin.  As for the table fields:
There are:
1. id (auto-increment)
2. user_id (int)
3. lat (Float)
4. lon (Float)
5. time (TimeStamp)

Comment: I wonder why a table would be called $session_name. Sounds like a maintenance nighmare!

Comment: @Strawberry It was originally a string and $session_name is a php variable, which contains the name of the table, at least that's how I understood the original question.

Comment: @maraca Yes. The implication being that the OP has a different table holding the same kind of information for every user.

Comment: @Strawberry One implication (bad indeed), it could mean many other things too. E.g. it could be the name of the application or module and not the username or it could come from configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with grouping is that you will need to join the original table again to get the rest of the columns. If you want to just get the latest row per user it's much easier with `not exists` (**works in almost any DBMS**):

```
SELECT user_id, lat, lon, time
FROM $session_name s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $session_name where user_id = s.user_id AND time > s.time)
```

`EXISTS` takes any `SELECT` command and returns `true` if there are any rows returned. `NOT` is the negation of it, similar as in `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. Usually we don't want to just select from some table to get some values (then we could use `IN` maybe), but we want to get very specific rows. In the query above we "bind" the `user_id` to only get results for the same `user_id` (we have to use an alias, `s` above, to make it work because of ambiguity) and additionally we add the condition that the time in the `NOT EXISTS` query is after the time of the row we are currently looking at, because if there is no row with later time then the current row is the latest for the user. Note that this query might return several rows per user, if it is possible that a user has two entries with the exact same timestamp.

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked like a charm.  Could I get an explanation of how the "not exists" work?

Comment: @notoriousnapper You're welcome, I like your name ;-) Added more details. This should work in almost any DBMS: postgresql, oracle, db2, mysql, ms sql server, ... Can you please accept the answer, if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

A sub query with window function should work, along these lines:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    lat,
    long,
    time
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        lat,
        long,
        time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC) as row_no
     FROM @session_name 
) u
WHERE row_no = 1
```

Or alternatively using LAST_VALUE window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id,
    LAST_VALUE(lat)  OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as lat,
    LAST_VALUE(long) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as long,
    LAST_VALUE(time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as time
FROM @session_name
```

Comment: The OP appears to be using MySQL